# ArrayAccess/ArrayObject do not work with functions like call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, magic-methods, arrayaccess

When implementing an object using `ArrayAccess` or `ArrayObject`, to some operations it's a perfectly normal array (for instance a `foreach()` statement). Others, however, are not so easily fooled and still complain it is an object:

```
[E_WARNING] call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given
```

This strikes me as incosistent. Can someone explain the reasoning behind this? Is there a way around this?

I need this to support backend code. It requires an array (passed as a parameter to `call_user_func_array()`), and sometimes modifies it. I need to mirror any changes made to the array to the new variables however, so that's why I tried to do it via an `ArrayAccess` object (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13137437/801042)).

Comment: Closed as too localized? Strongly disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thye function name is pretty explicit, and the [description in the documents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) indicates why it requires an array

The solution is to wrap your object inside an array

```
call_user_func_array('callback', array( $myObject));
```

Comment: Right, I understand. But why are `foreach` and `count()` able to adapt to the `ArrayObject` instead of an array, and other functions aren't? Still think it's inconsistent.

Comment: Because `ArrayObject` implements a `Traversable` and `Countable` interface which are that `foreach` and `count()` need.

Comment: Good point. It's a shame there is not an interface that supports some kind of `__toArray()` method :*( I'll accept your answer because this comment answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you cant use `ArrayObject` or and `ArrayAccess` implementor with native functions that operate on arrays. You can use them with language constructs that typically use array notation for traversing and what not.

Comment: Yes... `array_keys`, `array_values`, `array_map` etc..