# Using object implementing ArrayAccess and Iterator as variadic parameter

Tags: php, arrays, variadic

I have a class that implements both [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) and [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php).

I'm trying to figure out how to pass this object variadic parameter to a native function like `array_merge`:

```
array_merge(...$object);
```

To my disappointment I'm getting an error saying that `$object` is not an array.

```
array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array
```

I've looked at these other interfaces but non of them seem obvious: [IteratorAggregate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php), [Serializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php), [Countable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php). Also [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) turned out to be a dead end.

I do have a getter for to convert to array. But I was kind of hopping to discover my $object transform into an array just by implementing either ArrayAccess or Iterator, since it is about unfolding the array.

Is there another interface I can implement to make my class be more array-like?

Comment: Your `$object` is an array of arrays?

Comment: maybe interesting? [A PHP port of Underscore.js with additional functions and goodies](https://github.com/Anahkiasen/underscore-php)

Comment: @GentiSaliu my $object is an ArrayAccess implementation

Comment: @RyanVincent Underscore.php is similar to what I'm working on ([arrgh](https://github.com/mblarsen/arrgh)) so they'd have the same issue.

Comment: I have no idea what the objects are that you implemented. What I do when I want an object that implements the array interfaces, is extend `ArrayObject` and override the 'offsetGet' etc. functions. The useful part is that it easy to access or replace the inherited array (array_copy).

Comment: @Michael How about to use `iterator_to_array()` function?

Comment: @felipsmartins, no the point is that PHP should unpack the object automatically if implementing some interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new language feature as documented in [the migration guide from 5.5.x to 5.6.x in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) (section *Argument unpacking via `...`*), you must be on a pre-`5.6.x` runtime.

If you cannot upgrade your runtime, you must make use of your getter for converting it to an array (similar to [`ArrayObject`'s `getArrayCopy`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)):

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr->getArrayCopy());
```

**Tests**

The code below (based on PHP's documentation examples for [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) and [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)) executed successfully on PHP `5.6.2`, `5.6.17` and `7.0.1`. It fails indeed on older versions (`5.5.31` and older).

```
$arr = new MyArray();
$arr[0] = array(1, 2);
$arr[1] = array(3, 4);

// MyArray
print(get_class($arr));

// Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) 
print_r(array_merge(...$arr));
```

Implementation of `MyArray`:

```
class MyArray implements ArrayAccess, Iterator
{
      private $container = array();
      private $position = 0;

      public function getArrayCopy() {
        return $this->container;
      }

      public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
      }

      public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
      }

      public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
      }

      public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
      }

      function rewind() {
        $this->position = 0;
      }

      function current() {
        return $this->container[$this->position];
      }

      function key() {
        return $this->position;
      }

      function next() {
        ++$this->position;
      }

      function valid() {
        return isset($this->container[$this->position]);
      }
}
```

Comment: `Iterator` extends `Traversable`. The question was not about using `foreach` on my object but about using my object as a variadic parameter on native functions like `array_map`.

Comment: This is the exact implementation I have. I realized that my internal array was holding more objects of the same class, thus returning objects (implementing ArrayAccess, Iterator of course). So I guess the conclusion is that it that the splat will unpack the object, but array_map still does not take other than native arrays :(

Comment: I guess I'm searching for something similar to `__toString()` that PHP will call when expects to find an array. `__toArray()` if you will.

Comment: This cannot be done, unfortunately. There are no magic methods for that. `array_map`, `array_merge` etc. require a native PHP array, as their name states. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121613/casting-object-to-array-any-magic-method-being-called, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140657/arrayaccess-arrayobject-do-not-work-with-functions-like-call-user-func-array